# Search for specific string VBA Excel/PPT

Tags: vba, excel, replace

Using the attached code, If I have a filename (jpg) called "Haunting, The" How can I get it (as it's looping through) to look for a file called "The Haunting" OR "The, Haunting?"

This is for Excel that is populating a PPT, and I am trying to load the images whilst not changing the file structure of the actual source folder.

Thank you so much

As you can see below, I have a replace for Special Characters, and then it uses convertedstring to get the image name

```
                        convertedstring = originalstring
                        For Each char In Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")
                            convertedstring = Replace(convertedstring, char, " ")
                        Next
```

---

```
        For Each oPPtShp In pptSlide.Shapes.Placeholders

            ' Run the Error handler "ErrHandler" when an error occurs.
            Const SpecialCharacters As String = "!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),{,[,],},:,."

            Dim originalstring  As String
            Dim convertedstring As String

            On Error Resume Next

            '~~> Only need to work on Picture place holders
            If oPPtShp.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderPicture Then
                With oPPtShp
                    oPPtShpName = oPPtShp.Name
                    pptSlide.Shapes(oPPtShpName).Select

                    If oPPtShp.Name = oPPtShpName And Imagenum = 1 Then paths = "C:\"
                    If oPPtShp.Name = oPPtShpName And Imagenum = 2 Then paths = "C:\"
                    If oPPtShp.Name = oPPtShpName And Imagenum = 3 Then paths = "C:\"

                    If oPPtShp.Name = oPPtShpName And Imagenum = 1 Or oPPtShp.Name = oPPtShpName And Imagenum = 2 Then originalstring = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
                    convertedstring = originalstring
                    For Each char In Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")
                        convertedstring = Replace(convertedstring, char, " ")
                    Next


                    If oPPtShp.Name = oPPtShpName _
                    And Imagenum = 1 Then
                        pptSlide.Shapes.AddPicture _
                            paths & convertedstring & ".jpg", _
                            msoFalse, msoTrue, .Left, .Top, .Width, .Height
                    ElseIf oPPtShp.Name = oPPtShpName _
                    And Imagenum = 2 Then
                        pptSlide.Shapes.AddPicture _
                            paths & convertedstring & " - Copy" & ".jpg", _
                            msoFalse, msoTrue, .Left, .Top, .Width, .Height
                    ElseIf oPPtShp.Name = oPPtShpName _
                    And Imagenum = 3 Then
                        pptSlide.Shapes.AddPicture _
                            paths & convertedstring & " - Copy (2)" & ".png", _
                            msoFalse, msoTrue, .Left, .Top, .Width, .Height

                    End
                    DoEvents

                End With
                Imagenum = Imagenum + 1
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: As is, the question is too broad. Can you edit to point us to the specific spot in the code that does the looping and that you are having issues modifying?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a try.

If `originalstring = "Haunting, The"`

The the following will result in `The Haunting`

```
Sub test()
    Dim originalstring As String
    Dim convertedstring As String
    Dim iCommaLocation As Integer

    iCommaLocation = InStr(1, originalstring, ",")
    originalstring = "Haunting, The"
    convertedstring = Right(originalstring, Len(originalstring) _
                                            - iCommaLocation _
                                            - 1) _
                      & " " _
                      & Left(originalstring, iCommaLocation _
                                             - 1)
End Sub
```

Then you can look for both the `originalstring` and `convertedstring`

This will not work, however, if you have multiple commas in the string.